# Extracting search results data using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with scraping data from linkedin. I was able to login with selenium in python and navigate it to the desired page I want to  scrape. How ever I am facing challenges in gathering the data.

[image]

From the above image, you can see I have 22 results, I need to put those 22 results into csv file and defined by name, roles, company, months in role, etc.,

I am using selenium for this.

below is the html :

```
<a data-control-id="ù*ì/tH»=Ô¨w" data-control-name="view_lead_panel_via_search_lead_name" href="/sales/lead/ACwAAANJP7UBNIhbRLwsmhj5uyYeaOLU6ktthT4,NAME_SEARCH,Kksu?_ntb=ZnuIJGhESLutEc3rMsX2uQ%3D%3D" id="ember159" class="ember-view" data-lead-search-result="profile-link-st154">
              <span data-anonymize="person-name">Alain Cauwenberghs</span>
            </a>
```

below is the code:

```
name_html = soup1.find('a', {'class': 'ember-view'})
name_titles = []

for title in name_html:
    name_titles.append(title.text.strip())
 
print(name_titles)
```

Please help me, as I am not getting all the names in the list. I need all the names in the list. I am using beautiful soup.

Comment: _I am using beautiful soup_: Why tagging [tag:selenium-webdriver] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find the names you can use the `data-anonymize` attribute in order to find the spans with names.

```py
soup1 = ...

titles = soup1.find_all("span", {"data-anonymize": "person-name"})
names = []

for name in titles:
    names.append(name.text)

print(names)

# with provided HTML sample it outputs:
# ['Alain Cauwenberghs']
```

Comment: I think you missed the problem here, OP is asking, why is she not able to fetch all the names, and your code might be better at choosing the name, but it also picks only one.

Comment: @Zero it's because the sample only has 1 name in it. I'll change it to `find_all` in order to reflect Shusmitha's wishes.

Comment: @Sushmitha could you provide details?

Comment: @kggn I am getting empty list

Comment: @Sushmitha is the HTML identical to the HTML provided before? Could you send a sample?